# Any way of detecting whether a browsers console is able to render colors?

Tags: javascript, console

Is there a way of checking to see if a browser is capable of using console colors without sniffing?

```
console.log('%c Oh my heavens! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
```

For example that in chrome 26+ and firebug will print colored output.

Comment: Why you need to print colors in consol? it is only for debugging purpose

Comment: I am building a debugging tool in js...

Comment: Why does someone who only asks 'why do you need...' get a +1? I hate that question! Why is it relevant why someone needs something?

Answer (score 11):

This is one of these few cases where browser version detection seems the valid way to go. To minimize the dangers of this approach make sure to use a blacklist rather than a whitelist, no matter how unintuitive this might feel right now (to make sure you don't leave out new future browser as happened with a lot of old netscape focused code). I am aware that this isn't the answer you wanted to hear, but as `console.log` is a native function and it's effect can in no way be observed, so as far as I can see the only option is to do browser version detection.

Comment: Browser detection? Firefox does not support colors, while Firebug does.

Comment: I believed this to be obvious, but you can check that the firebug console is used using `(window.console.firebug || window.console.exception)`. The first will work for older firebug versions, but sadly firebug decided to remove this https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4772

Comment: You can also detect Firefox's built-in console through `console.__mozillaConsole__`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote Console.js https://github.com/icodeforlove/Console.js to allow us to do this a bit easier

```
Console.styles.register({
  red: 'color: red',
  underline: 'text-decoration: underline',
  bold: 'font-weight: bold'
});
```

then you can just do this

```
console.log('red text '.red + 'red underlined text'.red.underline + 'red bold text'.red.bold);
```

it will gracefully degrade like this

[image: console.js example]

Comment: Nice library, how did you detect if colors can be used or not?

Comment: @lededje unfortunately browser detection (https://github.com/icodeforlove/Console.js/blob/master/src/Console.js#L12)

Comment: Nice library, but doesn't answer the question. Only the comment answers the question.

Comment: At this point in time color support within consoles is above 95%.

When this question was originally asked it was less than 40%.

The answer was user-agent sniffing. Since then the library listed above as moved from supporting legacy browsers to just using the modern API, and making styling easier.