# Is it possible to detect console CSS support?

Tags: javascript, browser, console

In most modern browsers you can write:

```
console.log('%cfoo', 'color:red');
```

and end up with `foo` in red.  I'm wondering if anyone knows how to feature-detect this?  Specifically for older versions of browsers so you're not left with:

```
> %cfoo color:red
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way of detecting whether a browsers console is able to render colors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485093/any-way-of-detecting-whether-a-browsers-console-is-able-to-render-colors)